# AzureML , using training artifactes during inference

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I built a ML training pipeline in which I used ohe=OneHotEncoding() for the training data. Now I want to transform the inference data using the same ohe object. How can I make this ohe object available in my inference job? I am using Azure ML SDK v2.

I am trying to find out ways to make sure that the ohe object is available in the Inference Deployment , but cant find out anything.

Comment: Can you please add more details test data that you are passing to the inference job?

Answer (score 0):

The model artifacts can be downloaded using az ml model download - that will get all of the files.

Create production ML pipelines with Python SDK v2 - [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-pipeline-python-sdk)